# How to set a timeout for connect() and how to measure it?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, connection-timeout

I am writing a small network utility, in which somewhere in my code I have the following lines:

```
if (connect(sock, addr_result->ai_addr, addr_result->ai_addrlen) < 0)
  syserr("connect");
```

I have two questions regarding timeouts:

1. How can I set a timeout for `connect()` using Linux API?
2. If I wanted to measure timeout by myself, what would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Register signal handler for SIGALARM. set alarm before calling connect and clear alarm after connect returns, if you hit signal handler then it's connection timeout.

Answer (score 1):

use non-blocking connect and use select or poll or epoll for timeout. Here is the sample.

```
int fd = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0); 
int flags = fcntl(fd,F_GETFL); 
if (flags >= 0)
   flags = fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK); 
int n = connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof addr); 
if(n < 0) 
{  
    if(errno != EINPROGRESS && errno != EWOULDBLOCK) 
        return 1; 

    struct timeval tv; 
    tv.tv_sec = 10; 
    tv.tv_usec = 0; 
    fd_set wset; 
    FD_ZERO(&wset); 
    FD_SET(fd,&wset); 
    n = select(fd+1,NULL,&wset,NULL,&tv); 
    if(n < 0) 
    {
        close(fd); 
        return 1; 
    } 
    else if (0 == n) 
    { // timeout
        cerr<< "Timeout." << endl; 
        close(fd); 
        return 1; 
    } 
    else 
    {  // connect success
        cerr << "Connectd." <<endl; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the socket to non-blocking, issue the `connect(),` then use `select()` or `poll()` or `epoll()` with a timeout, selecting for writability.

I don't know what you mean by 'measure the timeout'.